# highcharts / Angular databinding with series

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm not that experienced with highcharts and struggeling with binding my data into the series parameter.

I've got a controller that - besides other logic - offers an array of objects i want to display (console.log offers them all properly)

```
this.plotData = [];
```

which is pushed by

```
this.plotData.push({
                  name: dataport,
                  data: this.plotFromData(this.device.data[dataport]),
                })
```

with 3 objects in it, that include `name "String"` and `data []`.
I would like to bind them into my chart controller with

```
series: [{
     data: this.plotData[0],
     name: 'this.name'
    },
data: this.data[1],
     name: 'a String name'

        }, ...
```

for each data provided. But nothing is rendered properly except for the String i added to check the binding. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to render more than one Graph in Highcharts you need to populate the Series Property which is an array of Objects like the following :

```
series : [
  {name: 'myName1' , data: myDataSet1} , 
  {name: 'myName2' , data: myDataSet2}
]
```

You do not illustrate something like that in your example.

The `myDataSet` should be an `Array()` of Arrays like the following :

```
var myDataSet = [ 
  [timestamp , value] , 
  [timestamp , value] , 
  [timestamp , value] 
];
```

So at the end you should have :

```
series : [
  {   
      name: 'myName1' , 
      data: [ 
        [timestamp , value] , 
        [timestamp , value] , 
        [timestamp , value] 
      ]
  } , 
  {
    name: 'myName2' , 
    data: [ 
       [timestamp , value] , 
       [timestamp , value] , 
       [timestamp , value] 
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: the provided data is an array with objects that contain timestamps and values. So i thought i could display each object with it's array of data by `data: plotData[0] ` - or do i need to change how the data is provided and separate it first?

Comment: The "series" property needs an Array of Arrays of Timestamp / Value pairs , it will not work with an Array of Objects. Check out this link which describes the "series" property thoroughly. It will help you solve your issue: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series